# 400 response on only some/random calls to acquire access token using U/P?

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Built a pseudo-SSO where the user provides their Azure credentials and we use Microsoft Graph to determine if they have the right security groups to enter. It's a public client enterprise app reg. This allows us to provide the Username/Password and client/tenant ID to retreive an access token as well as make two calls to Graph for information. Everything was working fine until recently.

Here is the chunk of code that is throwing a 400 error... but only sporadically.

```
context = new AuthenticationContext( authorityID, false, service );
Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken( "https://graph.microsoft.com", clientID, username, password, null );
result = future.get();
```

I'm unsure why this error is occurring seemingly randomly; some users are able to log-in immediately while others have to make 2-3 attempts to get through. The error message is provided below, a vague Bad Request message. Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

```
ERROR: Unable to create authentication result and retrieve access token from the given credentials.
com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/userrealm/[usernamehere] ?api-version=1.0, Error details : 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><Bad Request
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Any guidance or suggestions are greatly appreciated! I'm a new dev in need of some recommendations on what to look for with an error happening randomly like this.

Comment: just a (crazy)n idea (since there is nothing "obvious" ..since "random" :( ): ...is it possible that some other "thread" messes up (any of) your `authorityID, clientID, username, password`? ...otherwise i would blame "the environment" (random: i also often connect to "load balancing"...:(

Comment: ...for the first one a `401` would be more reasonable.

Comment: @xerx593 it definitely seems to be an environment thing considering it 100% doesn't show this error on another environment, I appreciate these ideas :) the randomness is definitely throwing us off